# data not being written to csv with Apache Commons

Tags: java, csv, javafx, apache-commons

I am trying to run the following code with apache commons, in order to write it a to csv file.  The print statement for the `finalResult` array shows that it has what I wanted populated in it.  It just does not send the data inside to the designated csv for some reason.

```
public void handle(ActionEvent runButton) {
    String csvFile = (userHomeFolder + "/" + fileName.getText() + ".csv");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);
    try {

        final Object [] FILE_HEADER = columnHeaders.toArray();
        int modval = 2;
        final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
        FileWriter fileWriter;
        CSVPrinter csvFilePrinter;
        CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
        List rowResult = new ArrayList();

        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName.getText());
        csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);

        try {

            //CREATE CSV FILE HEADER
            System.out.println("File header: " + FILE_HEADER);
            csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

            for(int y = 0; y < finalResult.size(); y++) {

                if(y % modval == 0) {
                    rowResult.add(finalResult.get(y));
                    csvFilePrinter.printRecord(rowResult);
                    System.out.println(rowResult);
                    rowResult.clear();
                }else {
                    //this means it is not the last value in the row
                    rowResult.add(finalResult.get(y));
                    System.out.println("fr: " + finalResult.get(y));
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in csvFileWriter");
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
                csvFilePrinter.close();
            } catch (IOException e ) {
                System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing");
            }
        }
    }
}
    //below catches any errors for any of the above work
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
   }
```

Comment: You use a conventional `try` without a `catch` or `finally` or resource declaration which is why this does not compile! Furthermore it would probably be best to close underlying writers after the wirter using them since you do not know if they use buffering...

Comment: can you add the contents of finalResult to the question. also when you execute what do you see as a result of your two printout statements?

Comment: Why do you have two `FileWriter`s? It seems  you only ever write to one of them - which isn't the one with the 'csv' suffix?

Comment: @sillyfly csvFilePrinter uses FileWriter

Comment: There is a `FileWriter` called `writer`, and one called `fileWriter`. The one called `writer` is never used after its creation, and is the one actually intialized with the .csv suffix.

Comment: @sillyfly ahh... i missed that. :)

Comment: @fabian I do have that in my code, however I accidentally left it out when copying over.  Edited above code to reflect.  Also the output has sensitive info, so I cannot.  But the layout is `[{string, string}, {string, string}]` if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need dozens of lines of code and a third-party library to do what can be done with `printf` in probably 5 lines? Create a `PrintWriter` and write with `printf`. Done.

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(csvFile)) {
    pw.printf("%s\n", FILE_HEADER);

    for(int i = 0; i < finalResult.size(); i+=2) { // no need to modulo
        pw.printf("%s\n", finalResult.get(i)); // no idea what type finalResult.get(i) is, format it if you need to
    }
}
```

You shouldn't be creating `csvFile` by hard-coding the file separator `/`, but that's another issue.

Comment: The reason for the complex code was because it needs to handle an unknown amount of columns, based on user input.  Then I want it to write to a csv and create a new line every time the index hits the size of the column header array so that it is neatly formatted.  i just simplified code to get to main issue solution quicker

Comment: You can do all that in the code above. You don't need to know the number of columns, just append whatever you have with `,` and print.